# How to create dynamic table pages while using jquery tablesorter?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have the following table code:

```
<table id="table_results" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Restaurant</th>
        <th>Region</th>
        <th>Settlement</th>
        <th>Kashrut</th>
        <th>Num of Seats</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <?php
    foreach ($restaurants as $key => $restaurant) {
        $region = get_region_by_id("restaurants", $restaurant['area']);
        echo '<tr><td>' . $restaurant['name'] . '</td><td>'
            . $region['name'] . '</td><td>' . $restaurant['city']
            . '</td><td>' . $restaurant['kosher'] . '</td><td>'
            . $restaurant['places_summer'] . '</td></tr>';
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

And this is the jquery javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#table_results").tablesorter(); 
});
```

I would like to create dynamic pages for the table (lets say in the table footer) for when ***$resturants*** exceeds 15 rows. Each page should have 15 results.
I thought about using jquery tabs, however it doesn't work well with the tablesorter as the each tab will only save 15 results, and the sort will only apply for them, And I want the sort to work on ALL the table.

Anyone knows a good way to do it while preserving the tablesorter feature?

Edit - Example for outputed table:

```
<table id="table_results" class="table_results tablesorter tablesorter-default">
    <thead>
    <tr class="tablesorter-headerRow">
        <th data-column="0" class="tablesorter-header" tabindex="0"
            unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
            <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Restaurant</div>
        </th>
        <th data-column="1" class="tablesorter-header" tabindex="0"
            unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
            <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Region</div>
        </th>
        <th data-column="2" class="tablesorter-header" tabindex="0"
            unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
            <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Settlement</div>
        </th>
        <th data-column="3" class="tablesorter-header" tabindex="0"
            unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
            <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Kashrut</div>
        </th>
        <th data-column="4" class="tablesorter-header" tabindex="0"
            unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
            <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Num of Seats</div>
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>BP</td>
        <td>Haifa &amp; Area</td>
        <td>Haifa</td>
        <td>Kosher</td>
        <td>250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cafe Horesh Carmel</td>
        <td>Haifa &amp; Area</td>
        <td>Haifa</td>
        <td>Kosher</td>
        <td>120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ein Hamifratz</td>
        <td>Haifa &amp; Area</td>
        <td>Kibbutz Ein Hamifratz</td>
        <td>Kosher</td>
        <td>500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Guest House Haifa</td>
        <td>Haifa &amp; Area</td>
        <td>Haifa</td>
        <td>Kosher</td>
        <td>150</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: can you post the html that is being generated from this?

Comment: Done, It isn't aligned well in rows but it's what Ive got.

This is just a an example for 4 results.